# munin setup cannot add client

Tags: monitoring

in my LAN i am looking to install a monitoring system and i decided to use Munin. Most of my devices in my LAN are Debian based(Debian stretch or Raspbian). My LAN is 192.168.1.0/24. The IP 192.168.1.25 is on the RPI that it will have the Munin server part. The problem is that i cannot add devices to the server to get monitored. In the hosts i did install the munin-node package and in their `/etc/munin/munin.conf` i added the at the end `allow ^192\.168\.1\.25$`. In the Munin server in the file `/etc/munin/munin.conf` i added one part for each host:

```
[RPI1.localdomain]
address 192.168.1.24
use_node_name yes

[RPI2.localdomain]
address 192.168.1.23
use_node_name yes
```

unfortunately, in the Munin webpage i can see only one machine monitored and it is the localhost. How can i see the rest of the machines please?

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been solved by changing the name to /etc/hosts & hostname & reboot

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking the tick on the left side. That fill finish the question and it will not pop up again later.